# max_user_connections SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to know the solution to 
max_user_connections' active connections

> Could not connect: already has more than 'max_user_connections' active
>   connections

As my website is down.

Please help as soon as possible

Comment: You should do some research -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html

Comment: Probably you are under an attack of DoS.

Comment: If your site doesn't have that many visitors, its probably due to poor database connection coding. However, if you do routinely get lots of visitors, its possible that you have reached the maximum connections (you can increase it with the database configuration).

Comment: Close the connection just before script ends or if you are writing class, write database close in __destruct . This may help you.

Comment: @PhilCross in both cases it is poor database connection coding - not using connection pools.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos attack of DoS))) DDOS?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you need to make your code more reliable way. Please, verify that

- your scripts runs for no more than 0.1-0.2 sec
- database connection occurred only **once** per execution, not in the every function.

Comment: Perhaps he is using some free hosting if he is facing that limit.

Comment: Well, the problem is solved! Thanks for helping guys. And I don't know why all those negative votes -7 !! I am not lazy but when your website is down and there are too many users who access it daily, you have no time for search. You need help as soon as possible. That's why I posted the question before doing so many searches. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Ask your hosting company or who ever is hosting you to help you out on this one. They will be able to change the limit.

Comment: Well, the problem is solved. Thanks everyone who helped. I don't know why all these negative votes -7 !! I wasn't so lazy search about the problem guys, but when your website is down and too many users access it daily.. You'll have no time to search, you want to solve your problem as soon as possible. That's why I asked for help asap. Thanks all, anyway.